# bulk vps server

Tags: vps, dedicated-server

So I'm thinking about get a dedicated server and partition it myself,  any recommendation on hosting company that will allocate me /22, /23, etc? What is the cost associated?

Comment: Sounds like you should look at buying "real" hardware, and setting it up yourself. I'm not aware of anything in the $3 range anywhere.

Comment: Why do you need that many machines?  What about getting one big one and using Solaris zones or something similar?

Comment: any recommendation on hosting company that would let me buy a dedicated server then allocate those 200 to 1000 ips to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any decent web hosting provider will be able to provide you with the appropriate number of IP addresses as long as you can justify them.  This said, it's pretty hard to determine if those sorts of costs are going to be viable.  There's a couple of questions you need to answer first:

- Where is the server going to be hosted?

  - This will affect the cost of the hardware, collocation fees, network connections etc.
- What resources are you going to give the VPSes

  - CPU time
  - Disk space
  - Bandwidth
  - Memory (you said 64MB, is that a hard limit for all the VMs?  You're still looking at ~16GB of RAM for the server just on that basic spec)

Also, what sort of resource contention do you deem to be acceptable?  Given the broad scope of the question, I don't think you've really done enough research into this.

Answer (score 0):

The economics of it are doable.  All you need to do is find a hosting company willing to provide such a deal to you.

Answer (score 0):

There is one in Germany that would fit the price: http://www.netcup.de/bestellen/produkt.php?produkt=88

But I think the better solution would be to use a cloud computing hoster like RackspaceCloud to manage this amount of vServers.

Comment: that looks cool, is there an english version?

Comment: As far as I know there's no english version that would be similar to what netcup provides.

Comment: Given that the minimum spend per VM for Rackspace Cloud VMs is ~$11, I don't think this really falls within his budget

Answer (score 0):

Burst.net has VPS around $4 with coupon. I couldn't use it because it doesn't support virtual memory so I opted for the $6 VPS.